# MySQL and HBase Connectivity

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase

I am new to Hadoop. I want to get data from mysql to Hbase continuously(Continuous Integration) and vice versa as well.
Is there any way to do this type of stuff ??

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Apache Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/): a tool designed for transferring bulk data between Hadoop and datastores such as relational databases.

Comment: Thank for the reply Alexander, But I want a continuous integration or what we say a migration from MySQL to HBase. I think with a use of Sqoop I will be able to export a dump file of MySQL and Import it to HBase, but it will not be a continuous migration.