# How to connect Hbase with Mysql

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am transferring my MySQL database to hdfs. I am using Hadoop and HBase. I have installed Hadoop and HBase, and both are working fine.
Now I want to connect HBase with MySQL, and continuously send data from my MySQL db to Hadoop/HBase.

Comment: What do you mean by "connect hbase with mysql". Transfer the data? Use both in an application? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-hadoop-applier.html

I think you might be looking for something like Sqoop 
http://sqoop.apache.org/

Also this was just asked :)  [MySQL and HBase Connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436794/mysql-and-hbase-connectivity)

After you comment below, I think you might find Hive useful - https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/07/11/mysql-and-hadoop/

Comment: Thanks Polaris .I am able to imprort and export data with sqoop.but I want to continuous integration .Do you have any idea please suggest me.

Comment: Do you have an automation tool like Jenkins? You can use Jenkins to have the scoop job run every few minutes maybe? If scoop is doing the job that it needs to, and you dont need this data in real time, this might be the best option as of now. However, you might want to look into Hive, as I think it is the solution you are looking for - https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/07/11/mysql-and-hadoop/